# Change JAVA_HOME in docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

The legacy web application which I want to dockerise uses some old classes like `com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException` which were supported till Java SE7. 
Now in the docker container default jdk getting (on installing tomcat-6 container) is

```
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1)
```

OpenJdk doesn't support these classes

I used `update-alternatives` to install Oracle Jdk7.80

After loading container, on giving `java -version` I am getting

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

However, `echo $JAVA_HOME` after entering the container gives `/docker-java-home/jre` which again points to OpenJdk. How can I set `JAVA_HOME` to the Oracle Jdk home that I installed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply set/change environment variables of your docker image by using the `ENV` command in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /path/to/java
```

Answer (score 5):

If your base image contains by default OpenJDK and If you want to use OracleJDK in your image just add the below command to your dockerfile  and build the image and boom your image will have oracle JDK.

```
RUN yum -y remove java***
RUN yum localinstall -y jdk-8u212-linux-x64.rpm && \
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")" | tee 
    -a /etc/profile && source /etc/profile && echo $JAVA_HOME && \
    rm jdk-8u212-linux-x64.rpm && \ 
    alternatives --set java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_212-amd64/jre/bin/java
```