# Install Oracle JDK8 on Docker Debian 10 (Buster)

Tags: java, docker, version

I want to install `Oracle JDK8` on a Docker Debian 10 (Buster) container.  The default container Java is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Where JAVA_HOME is

```
/usr/local/openjdk-8
```

Following numerous example on Stack and around the web, I have performed the following without success:

- Downloaded the [official Oracle image](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Install the image via `Dockerfile` build:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5
MAINTAINER joco

# set up tomcat app
COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY /libs/* /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf

# install Oracle jdk8
COPY jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar zxvf /usr/local/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_202
RUN rm /usr/local/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz


EXPOSE 8080
```

Which unpacks the files and sets the JAVA_HOME environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_202
```

But java -version still points to

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Furthermore

```
# update-alternatives --list java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

> How do I set the java version to the Oracle JDK?

Other posts that I have reviewed (not comprehensive)

- [Change JAVA_HOME in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277631/change-java-home-in-docker/56035653)
- [Set JAVA_HOME on ubuntu docker Container](https://medium.com/@felixgondwe/set-java-home-on-ubuntu-docker-container-e302a7aa45ad)
- [Debian : Change default Java version](https://mkyong.com/linux/debian-change-default-java-version/)
- [Dockerize your Java Application](https://runnable.com/docker/java/dockerize-your-java-application) - General concepts here since this method is no longer valid with Oracle license changes.

Comment: what is the base image you are using? I mean repo and tag.

Comment: @michalk  `from tomcat:8.5`  - Normally the openJDK would work, except AWS has issues with it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add this info there ? (as well as any other missing parts of your Dockerfile if any...)